# keep variables in proc means

Tags: sas

I run the following code:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=count;
class advertiser;
var date;
output out = countdata N=Count;
RUN;
```

The dataset output gives me the variables Advertiser, Count, *Type*, *Freq*. I wanted to know how I can keep other variables in the dataset without doing any analysis on them. For example, just keep the date variable which lists all of the dates.

Comment: Suggest you show some sample data and the output you would want.  Perhaps using sashelp.class.  What would you want as output from: PROC MEANS DATA=sashelp.class;
class sex;
var age;
output out = want N=Count;
RUN;

Comment: Okay..I would want the following:

Sex       _Type_        _Freq_       Count     Date
F              1                  19              19         May2005
M             1                   10              9           May2005

Comment: I'm still confused, if you want one record per class level, I would put all the variables you want on class statement.  If you want one record per record in the input dataset, check out SQL.

Answer (score 5):

`PROC MEANS` has the `ID` statement, which allows you to do some of what you're asking for.

Since `PROC MEANS` is summarizing data, if you want multiple rows per `class` value, you can't get that directly; your best bet is to merge the `PROC MEANS` results to the dataset using `merge`.

However, if you want only one row per class value, and either you have variables that are always the same for the same class variable, or you are okay with the maximum/minimum value, you have options.

If there are only one value per (value of class variables), you can simply add the variable to the `class` statement, or to the `by` statement.  The latter may be better in some cases if you have a lot of class values (as it will tie up more resources to use it as class vs. by).

If you do have multiple values (or could), and don't want it in the `class` or `by` statements, then you can use the `ID` statement.  That by default places the maximum value on the output dataset (or with the `IDMIN` option on the `PROC` statement, puts the minimum value).

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  class age;
  types age;
  id name;
  var height weight;
  output out=classvars mean=;
run;
```

The id variable `name` is sort of silly on that, but it shows the example.

Answer (score 1):

PROC MEANS is summarizing by class variables.  If you want more variables in the output dataset you could list them on the class statement.   PROC SQL will let you compute counts by a grouped variable, and then output a dataset with the same number of records as the input dataset with the count column added ("remerged summary statistic").  Are either of these close to what you want:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class nway;
  class sex age;
  var height;
  output out = want N=Count_Height;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want2 as
  select *,count(height) as Count_Height
  from sashelp.class
  group by sex
  ;
quit;
```